# Distinguish alternating rows color from selection color in QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem, qpalette

I have two `QTableWidget`s, that should synchronize their selection. More precisely everything selected in Table 2, should be automatically selected in Table 1.

Everything works fine, but if I'm setting the property `setAlternatingRowColors` to true, I have a visual problem. (I'm thinking that setAlternatingRowsColors is a great feature.)

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QTableWidget>
#include <QHBoxLayout>

QTableWidget* create() {
    auto table = new QTableWidget;
    table->setAlternatingRowColors(true);
    table->setSortingEnabled(true);
    table->setRowCount(20);
    table->setColumnCount(2);
    for (auto i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        {
            auto item = new QTableWidgetItem(QString("%1").arg(i));
            table->setItem(i, 1, item);
        }
        {
            auto item = new QTableWidgetItem(QString("%1").arg(i));
            table->setItem(i, 0, item);
        }
    }
    return table;
}
int main(int argc, char** args) {
    QApplication app(argc, args);
    QTableWidget* table1 = create();
    QTableWidget* table2 = create();
    auto frame = new QFrame;
    frame->setLayout(new QHBoxLayout);
    frame->layout()->addWidget(table1);
    frame->layout()->addWidget(table2);
    frame->show();
    QObject::connect(table2, &QTableWidget::itemSelectionChanged, [&]() {
        table1->selectionModel()->clearSelection();
        for (auto item : table2->selectedItems()) {
            table1->item(item->row(), item->column())->setSelected(true);
        }
        table1->update();
    });
    app.exec();
}
```

Even though the selection of elements in odd rows is done as before, the user has no chance to see this selection. It seems that both colors are the same (But why is this so?).

[image: Selection indistinguishable from alternating row]

With this perspective there might be only two possible solutions. Either change the selection color or changing the color of the alternatingRows.

How can I change the color of the alternating rows consistently among the whole application, that might contain even more QTableWidgets?

Comment: Not that it really matters here, but you have a memory leak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (in main):

```
QString style = "QTableWidget { alternate-background-color: white; background-color: gray; }";
style.append(" QTableWidget::item:selected { background: red; }"); //selection color
QApplication::setStyleSheet(style);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Would this work among all QStyle's? (Actually, I'm only using windows, but I'm just curious.)

Comment: Actually, it works, but it has some side effects. It is also possible to change the selection color?

Comment: Sorry. There is no side effect. I just doesn't need to set `background-color: gray`.

Comment: Still. How can I change the selection color? Is this possible?

Comment: It says: QApplication, invalid style override passed, ignoring it. Does it work in your case? We are using Qt 5.8.

Comment: Edited again, sorry.

Comment: Works like charm. Many thanks for your fast reply. I'm wondering if QT misses this problem by accident or deliberately.